# Capitalization of "county" when used in certain context

Tags: capitalization

We are working to provide support to Xxxx County in the US.
We will do this, that and the other thing in support of the county/County.
Is county capitalized in the second sentence?

Comment: What research have you done? What style guide are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Not usually no, in this case Xxxx County is in the form of a Proper Noun and is capitalised accordingly but "the county" although it refers to the same geopolitical entity is a general article and is not therefore capitalised.

Comment: That would be widely open to interpretation even if "the county" was really "a general article" or anything other than the "generic noun" you proboably meant.

In theory that depends whether "County/county" is a generic term encompassing all counties, or an abbreviation for one, specifically - which in practice must mean how clearly it's an abbreviation. In this case, how clear is that?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin We can tell from the context supplied by the OP that the second sentence's noun phrase that refers to the county is a generic noun: it omits the Xxxx which would be necessary to identify the county, and it has the determiner "the" (and the first sentence shows that the county's name does not have an initial article). Ash is therefore correct.

Comment: Rosie, don't you think that depends more on writing style and context than any strict rule?

Do you insist we always use the full form Name-it County, even if that crops up five phrases, never mind sentences in a row?

By the way, what's an "initial article", please?